# Получение логов устройства и приложения

Tags: java, android, логирование, logcat

Добрый день! Помогите мне решить проблему. Не подскажите, как получить все логи (не только приложения, но и железки) программно? 
Я использовал:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -d -v threadtime");
byte[] data = process.getInputStream()).getBytes()
```

Но данный метод позволяет получить только логи приложения, а хотелось бы получить все логи.
Если в bash вызвать эту же команду(logcat -d -v threadtime) то получаю все логи, в том числе и устройства.

Заранее спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

нужно добавить в манифест строку:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
```